# Format usb drive (dmg is on - and show read only)

Tags: macos, usb

I have a problem to format/erase an usb drive with mac os x on it. It shows that drive is read only. 
[image: SanDisk usb disk]

[image: Read only?]

[image: disk verifying]

[image: SanDisk Cruzer Force Media]

Is there any way that I can format/erase disk to become writable?

Comment: yes I'm log in as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i remember this from a few years ago -- there were a lot of these slipping into RO mode.  here is a forum talking about it: http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/Sandisk-cruzer-16GB-became-read-only/td-p/255218/page/2

with no real solution.  it is a hardware issue, regarless of operating system etc.

Comment: usb key is dead ...